# Carrierwave json column with metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, carrierwave, fog

I am making file uploader that in addition to storing multiple files to s3 using fog also needs to store additional information such as file name, etc for each file.

Since number of files for one row can vary I'd like to save this data in my database table in form of json. However, carrierwave by default stores only url of the uploaded file.

Json would have structure similar to this:

```
{
    {
        url: ...,
        name: ...
    },
    {
        url: ...,
        name: ...
    }
}
```

Has anyone tried doing this and how would one go about it?

Comment: you're asking for the multiple file storage or just for the metadata (url, name)?

Comment: I need multiple file storage but each file has separate file field with few additional text fields that need to to together. So, each group containing file and text fields is one nested json in my table column.

Answer (score 0):

I would implemente it either with a callback (if it gets called for each file) or a process (if callback gets called for all files at once), on the uploader:

[Carrierwave Callbacks](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-use-callbacks)

```
your_uploader.rb

after :store, :save_json_info
```

or

```
process :save_json_info


def save_json_info
  info = model.json_field
  info[filename] = {
    url: ...,
    name: ...
  }
  model.update!(json_field: info)
end
```

(inside the uploader you actually reference the model which is being saved to as literal `model`)

Then you could access them by
(outside you'll substitute model for it's actual name...)

```
 name = model.avatar[0].file.filename
```

or

```
 name = model.avatar[0].split('/')[-1] #this is a hacky way of getting the filename, by splitting the url address and getting the last element of the split 

 model.json_field[name]
```

(i'm not sure this is the correct way to access multiple files on carrierwave but whatever it is it should be similar)

EDITED:
And probably the best way would be to have the json field be an array as well, and then simply << { url: '...', name: '....' } on the field as you go through processing the files. Then when you loop through the files to show them you can loop with the index and get the corresponding json values for it.

So on your uploader you would have:

```
def save_json_info
  model.json_field << {
    url: ...,
    name: ...
  }
  model.save!
end
```

Then if you're looping through the images, .each_with_index for instance, you can use the index to access model.json_field[i]. Since I imagine files will be added to the array file field as they are processed, pushing them into the info_json array field in the same cycle will render the same index for both. You'll need to take care of when they're removed though.